# How to change the shape of the canvas itself?

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas, size, p5.js

I'm working on a project and I use createCapture(VIDEO); using p5js libraries, to get the video using my web camera. Then I store every image of that capture (from < video> element) and draw it in a canvas in the function draw().

I was wondering if it's possible the change the shape of the canvas(such as a mirror for example (oval or circle)).

Again, notice that I don't want to crop the image but the canvas itself.

Here is some code:

```
function setup(){

   canvas = createCanvas(640, 480); //480p
   canvas.parent('editedCanvas-container');

   originalCapture = createCapture(VIDEO);
   originalCapture.parent('originalVideo-container');
   originalCapture.size(640, 480); //480p
}

function draw(){

   frame = image(originalCapture, 0, 0, width, height);
}
```

If somebody has a clue please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the shape of your `canvas` tag by applying css rules,

So try this css code

```css
#canvasObject {
  border: 2px solid black;
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
  border-radius: 100px / 50px;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvasObject">
</canvas>
```

For more info about how to achieve shapes in css, please refer this amazing post for [css-tricks](https://css-tricks.com/the-shapes-of-css/)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. Implementing css commands works on the canvas however the dimensions of the canvas have been set through the javascript file (canvas = createCanvas(640,480)), so when i try to change it with CSS only the border and border-radius commands worked.

Comment: @LoizosVasileiou exactly your dimensions canvas is set by JS, but the css rule that you really matters should be `border-radius`, in the code example above I set the dimensions to the canvas as a example, but the css rule that you need to use is the `border-radius`